# Jetpack Compose will not recompose if function is called directly from textbutton onClick()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a function that should clear an List ( guessArray ) removing all the text from the view. If this function is called from anywhere including composables it seems to work, except for when it is called from the onClick of an AlertDialog.

updated vars:

```
var guessArray = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) }.toMutableStateList() }
private var column = 0
private var greenLetterList = mutableListOf<String>()
private var yellowLetterList = mutableListOf<String>()
private var grayLetterList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

function:

```
fun newGame() {
    greenLetterList.clear()
    grayLetterList.clear()
    yellowLetterList.clear()
    guessArray = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) }.toMutableStateList() }
    currentRow = 0
    column = 0
}
```

AlertDialog:

```
@Composable
fun GameEndPopUp(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.gameIsInPlay) }
    if (!openDialog.value.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value.value = true },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value.value = true
//this doesnt work
                        viewModel.newGame()
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(53.dp)
                        .height(50.dp),
                )
                { Text(text = "Next Word") }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Could it be that specifically AlertDialogs are the problem here? Calling from this onClick works perfectly:

```
@Composable
fun MyEnterButton(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    Button(
        onClick = {
            if (viewModel.gameIsInPlay.value) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    if (viewModel.checkWordExists()) {
                        viewModel.checkLetterPlacementIsCorrect()
                        viewModel.checkKeyboard()
       //this works
                        viewModel.newGame()
                    } else {
                        viewModel.toastWordNotFound(mContext)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code sets the variable `guessArray` to a new mutable state.
This will not trigger recomposition because the state your composable observes does not change.

```
guessArray = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) }.toMutableStateList() }
```

I would write this code quite differently, but the minimal change that might work for you is changing the line in `newGame()` to:

```
guessArray.value = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) } }
```

Then you will be updating the mutable state of `guessArray`, which should trigger recomposition.
You should also change guessArray from `var` to `val`.

**Edit:** This is more like how I would do it:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    /* 
        Rest of the home screen UI here
    */

    if (viewModel.state.value.showGameEndPopUp) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { viewModel.onDismissGameEndPopUp() },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.onNextWordClick()
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(53.dp)
                        .height(50.dp),
                )
                { Text(text = "Next Word") }
            }
        )
    }
}

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(HomeUiModel())
    val state: State<HomeUiModel> = _state

    data class HomeUiModel(
        val column: Int = 0,
        val showGameEndPopUp: Boolean = false,
        val greenLetterList: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val yellowLetterList: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val grayLetterList: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val guessArray: List<List<CardData>> = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) }}
    )

    fun onDismissGameEndPopUp() {
        _state.value = _state.value.copy(showGameEndPopUp = false)
    }

    fun onNextWordClick() {
        // Start a new game
        _state.value = HomeUiModel()
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here though is that guessArray has no .value, and leaving that out gives me Type mismatch.
Required:
List<SnapshotStateList<CardData>>
Found:
List<List<CardData>>

Comment: Aha. I don't think you want a list of states of lists, but a state of list of lists. Could try making guessArray a `MutableState<List<List<CardData>>>` instead.

`val guessArray = mutableStateOf(List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) }})`


Edit: Or maybe you want: 
`val guessArray = List(5) { List(6) { CardData("", Color.White) } }.toMutableStateList()`

Comment: This could be a possible way, but it then leads to me having to change a lot as most functions use .get  `fun addLettersToGrid(text: String) {
guessArray[currentRow][column] = CardData(text, Color.White)
 column += 1 } `  Im still confused though as to why some composables can call this but not this particular one..

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all your code, but my guess would be that in one of your cases parts of your state/data does not change, so recomposition does not happen: 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#skips

Comment: In case you're interested in having a look: https://github.com/pleavinseven/WordlCompose , I'll check the link out now and see if it can help me at all..

Comment: Made it work and created a pull request for your repo: https://github.com/pleavinseven/WordlCompose/pull/1